# How to create a trigger function that runs whenever the state changes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using localStorage for my project, and I want to update the localStorage everytime the state changes. I've read the documentation and I found a lifecycle method called `shouldComponentUpdate()` so I have two questions. Is it possible to be used in a functional component? and Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your react version have react hooks? If yes you can use the code below

```
useEffect(() => {
// change the localStorage
}, [state]);
```

this hook listens for updates of the variable inside the square brackets